# Using pre_get_posts on a specific core/query block

Tags: wp-query, block-editor, pre-get-posts

I’m trying to apply the `pre_get_posts` to a specific *core/query* block, in order to programatically modify the number of posts displayed when a custom attribute is set. If I use the `render_block` hook, the block is already pre-rendered and so modifying the query using `pre_get_posts` has no effect. Is there any way to achieve this?

(I don't need help adding the custom attribute; I've done so already using block filters.)

Comment: Maybe similar https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/392915/26350

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

It's possible to use the [`render_block_data`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block_data/) filter to modify the query block's data before it's rendered.

Since 6.1. the [`query_loop_block_query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_loop_block_query_vars/) filter is available if one needs to modify the underlying `WP_Query` arguments (e.g. those that are still unsupported by the query block's interface) but it only works for the front-end but not the editor preview that uses the REST API (see more on that in the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/#making-your-custom-query-work-on-the-front-end-side)).

**Original answer:**

There's an open ticket for such a query args filter [#54850](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/54850).

In the meanwhile you can try this approach, replacing the render callback of the `core/post-template` block with a wrapper callback:

```
add_filter( 'block_type_metadata_settings', function( $settings ) {
    if ( $settings['parent'][0] !== 'core/query' ) {
        return $settings;
    }
    if ( $settings['render_callback'] !== 'render_block_core_post_template' ) {
        return $settings;
    }
    $settings['render_callback']= 'wpse_render_block_core_post_template';
    return $settings;
});
```

with the wrapper callback as:

```
function wpse_render_block_core_post_template($attributes, $content, $block ){
    $output = render_block_core_post_template( $attributes, $content, $block );
    return $output;
}
```

Now we have a better way to target the `WP_Query` instance within that core template.

Following are two such examples.

### Example with `pre_get_posts`

Here's an example how to override the *number of posts* with the help of the `pre_get_posts` hook:

```
function wpse_render_block_core_post_template( $attributes, $content, $block ) {
    $cb = fn( $q ) => $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
    
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', $cb, 999 );
    $output = render_block_core_post_template( $attributes, $content, $block );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', $cb, 999 );

    return $output;
}
```

### Example with block context

We could also change existing query arguments within [`build_query_vars_from_query_block()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7b880889bc92552cdab7b0dd700db82a3885d02d/wp-includes/blocks.php#L1097), like `perPage`, with:

```
function wpse_render_block_core_post_template( $attributes, $content, $block ) {
    $block->context['query']['perPage'] = 2;
    return render_block_core_post_template($attributes, $content, $block );
}
```

Then you can add further restrictions as needed to both approaches, from e.g. other block info, like `queryId`.

Comment: Thanks for the link; the ticket was raised by a colleague with the same problem. That's a clever idea with the simple customisation of the render process.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code seems to have no effect. wpse_render_block_core_post_template is never called.

Comment: Try e.g. `$block->context['query']['perPage']=2;`  just before `render_block_core_post_template()` in our wrapper. This should also work to modify existing parameters (like perPage), not introducing new ones. @MarkHowells-Mead

Comment: Updated the answer with two examples @MarkHowells-Mead

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Re-defining the callback using `block_type_metadata_settings` works, but the render callback `wpse_render_block_core_post_template` is never called for the core/query block.

Comment: It seems to run on the frontend after quick testing in twentytwentytwo theme, inherit query is false. Not sure about within Gutenberg backend. To change the core/pagination query arguments, I think similar approach might help there as well.

Comment: I've amended the code within the `block_type_metadata_settings` callback above. I've passed in the second attribute `$metadata` to only continue if it's a core/query block. If it is, then I dump `$attributes`. The array entry `render_callback` isn't defined for the core/query block type, so the code above doesn't re-define it.

Comment: AH! Bingo. We were discussing at cross-purposes. The discussion was about the core/query block, but the workaround references the core/post-template block. Applying the code to the core/post-template block works.

Comment: great, sorry about that confusion, I was using the query block with a template block to test, and was checking if the query block was the parent. I will update.

Answer (score 1):

A modified version of the suggestion from @birgire works. Note that this applies to the `core/post-template` block, not the `core/query block`.

```
add_filter('block_type_metadata_settings', function ($settings, $metadata) {
    if ($metadata['name'] !== 'core/post-template') {
        return $settings;
    }
    if ($settings['render_callback'] !== 'render_block_core_post_template') {
        return $settings;
    }
    $settings['render_callback'] = 'wpse_render_block_core_post_template';
    return $settings;
}, 10, 2);

function wpse_render_block_core_post_template($attributes, $content, $block)
{
    $callback = fn ($query) => $query->set('posts_per_page', 2);

    add_action('pre_get_posts', $callback, 999);
    $output = render_block_core_post_template($attributes, $content, $block);
    remove_action('pre_get_posts', $callback, 999);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: good idea to use the metadata for better targetting